# On the Marshmallow,the MediaMetadataRetriever does not working

Tags: android

On the Marshmallow the `MediaMetadataRetriever` with `OPTION_CLOSEST,OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC,OPTION_NEXT_SYNC,OPTION_PREVIOUS_SYNC` does not work.

`The OPTION_CLOSEST` works fine with all versions of Android except Marshmallow. I tried to extract 30fps from video. Below is the code I used:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(33333*i,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
where, i-->1,2,3,...(next frames)
```

How can I extract 30fps in Android Marshmallow?

Comment: do you have `runtime permissions`?

Comment: yes, I have runtime permission for marshmallow.